# MySQL/PHP to generate values by date range

Tags: php, mysql

I've been reading plenty about crosstab reports (Pivot Tables) in PHP and I've been trying to complete a report but I'm stuck.

I have a DB Table with report_date, employee_name, employee_id, leader_name, leader_id, employee_dept, stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, stat6.

what I'm trying to do is to be able to query and return a sum and division of values based on the report_date range selected. So if I choose to query data between 10/01/2014 & 10/25/2014, I need it to sum and divide all the values found within that range.

This is my current SQL query.

```sql
Select
report_date,
employee_name,
employee_id,
leader_name,
leader_id,
employee_dept,
stat1,
stat2,
stat3,
stat4,
stat5,
stat6,
SUM(stat2)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name2`,
SUM(stat3)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name3`,
SUM(stat4)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name4`,
SUM(stat5)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name5`,
SUM(stat6)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name6`
FROM daily_records
GROUP BY report_date, employee_id
```

Might be too much to ask but how do I use this in PHP to query the totals from a selected report_date range?

Edited to add Sample data:

DB table data

```
report_date employee_id employee_name   employee_dept   STAT1   STAT2   STAT3   STAT4   STAT5   STAT6   leader_name leader_id
9/11/2014   1983122     emp_name1   ARK     17  7941    191 5   8137    2   Name        1001
9/11/2014   1983130     emp_name2   ARK     11  5067    516 3   5586    1   Name        1001
9/11/2014   1983138     emp_name3   ARK     3   184 16  4   204 1   Name        1001
9/11/2014   1983138     emp_name4   ARK     12  2576    7   6   2589    2   Name        1002
9/11/2014   1983138     emp_name5   ARK     21  9069    400 139 9608    1   Name        1002
9/11/2014   1983328     emp_name6   ARK     69  17929   1893    1096    20918   1   Name        1002
9/11/2014   1983349     emp_name7   ARK     12  2259    17  112 2388    2   Name        1002
9/11/2014   1983349     emp_name8   ARK     23  8194    880 211 9285    2   Name        1003
9/11/2014   1983829     emp_name9   ARK     81  16175   1431    311 17917   2   Name        1003
9/11/2014   1983888     emp_name10  ARK     7   1442    22  9   1473    1   Name        1003
9/12/2014   1983122     emp_name1   ARK     35  6823    774 22  7619    1   Name        1001
9/12/2014   1983642     emp_name2   ARK     80  18268   1439    135 19842   2   Name        1001
9/12/2014   1983643     emp_name3   ARK     55  20321   962 466 21749   1   Name        1001
9/12/2014   1983677     emp_name4   ARK     72  16379   1157    418 17954   2   Name        1002
9/12/2014   1983682     emp_name5   ARK     17  5017    419 425 5861    1   Name        1002
9/12/2014   1983978     emp_name6   ARK     48  9898    228 94  10220   1   Name        1002
```

(I tried to paste the table with a proper format but I couldn't)

Stats 2 to 6 should be divided by stat 1 to get a result for each field.
for example: stat2 / stat1 AS `Result Name`

Let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the exact outcome you're looking for based on the sample data

Comment: I added some sample data from the SQL table. 2 days worth of data. I'm sorry I couldn't format the table any better.

Comment: Go see about dates in mysql, and then get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `DATE` type for date. After append your query date condition like that;

```
Select
report_date,
employee_name,
employee_id,
leader_name,
leader_id,
employee_dept,
stat1,
stat2,
stat3,
stat4,
stat5,
stat6,
SUM(stat2)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name2`,
SUM(stat3)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name3`,
SUM(stat4)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name4`,
SUM(stat5)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name5`,
SUM(stat6)/SUM(stat1) AS `Result Name6`
FROM daily_records
WHERE report_date >= "2014-10-01"
OR report_date <= "2014-10-25"
GROUP BY employee_id`
```